# $http funciona no browser e não no aparelho android

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, http, ionic

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida utilizando **Ionic Framework**, é uma aplicação hibrida e nos teste feito no browser funcionou perfeitamente, quando gerei o arquivo .apk e testei tanto no emulador quanto no dispositivo não está executando a requisição. a função que está gerendo erro é:

```
$http.get('http://apps.widenet.com.br/busca-cep/api/cep.json?code='+cep)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      if(data.status == 1){
          $scope.respostas[0] = data;
        }
        else if (data.status == 0) {
          $scope.hasErros = true;
          $scope.erro = data.message;
        }
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.hasErros = true;
      $scope.erro = "Um erro inexperado ocorreu!";
    });
  }
})
```

Esse é a função que executa a requisição ao servidor, no entanto ela só cai na parte:

```
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.hasErros = true;
          $scope.erro = "Um erro inexperado ocorreu!";
        });
```

e sempre exibe a mensagem **"Um erro inexperado ocorreu!"**, isso quando executado pelo dispositivo, quando executado por um browser sempre da certo, alguém sabe como me ajudar ?

Comment: Eu tenho o mesmo problema o acess origin esta como vc havia informado e não funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colega, gere um apk de debug ( `ionic run android` ) e plugue seu phone via USB habilitando o `modo de depuração USB` no seu aparelho. Então abra a console do chrome no `developers tools` e debugue a app.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione no arquivo config.xml a opcao abaixo:

access origin="*"

exemplo

Caso ja exista remova os valores dentro do para origin e adicione o *.